# Is axios using cpu when he wait for response?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I was debugging client's app running on React, and I have a trouble with using too much CPU. When I was debuging, I need to remove one curious question from my head. When I send request to my server and waiting for response by axios module, can he take some CPU, while waiting on response? And if answer is yes, then how much he can take?

I was using Chrome's console and recording performance. Also I am using npm module axios@0.18.0.

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome console DevTools can drastically use CPU, for example: a single instance of React Chrome Devtools could take from 1 to 25 or more %